# Redirect query param and url param in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to make a complex url rewriting :

I have this url :

http://www.exemple.site/fr/slug-to-redirect.html?cmp_id=7&news_id=666

And need to redirect to this :

http://www.exemple.site/slug-to-redirect--666

In my current rewrite condition I was able to pick the query from the query_string but not the param from the url. How can we achieve this ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/fr/(.*)\.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} news_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*).html$ http://www.example.site/%2--%1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/fr/(.*)\?`

Comment: Sorry the correct url is : http://www.exemple.site/fr/slug-to-redirect.html?cmp_id=7&news_id=666

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} news_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.html$ /$1--%1 [R=302,L]
```

Use $1, $2, $... for () in the `RewriteRule`
And use %1, %2, %... for () in the `RewriteCond`

Answer (score 0):

This is why your rules don't work as expected:

> %1 to %9 provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses)
>   of the pattern, **from the last matched RewriteCond** in the current set
>   of conditions.

The answer from @Croises is correct, but as a more general way to use backreferences from multiple `RewriteCond`s, this may be used:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} news_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=PARAM1:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/fr/(.*)\.html
RewriteRule ^ - [E=PARAM2:%1]

RewriteRule ^fr/(.*).html$ http://www.example.com/%{ENV:PARAM2}--%{ENV:PARAM1}? [R=302,L]
```